# What are the possible return values of pthread_join when using pthread_cancel

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, pthread-join

The following code shows that I try to cancel the thread when the `start_routine` is not completed within the time `ts`, and join the thread to make sure the thread to terminate. I have used this on a simple function for `start_routine` and `res2` returns `PTHREAD_CANCELED`. However, I tried to use this approach for calling third party library in `start_routine` and this does not return `PTHREAD_CANCELED` (i.e. I got "pthread is terminated due to xxx?").

```
pthread_create(&thread, &attr, start_routine, (void *)&arg);
if (0 != pthread_timedjoin_np(thread, &res1, &ts)
{
    if (0 == pthread_cancel(thread))
    {
        if (0 == pthread_join(thread, &res2))
        {
            if (PTHREAD_CANCELED == res2)
            {
                std::cout << "pthread is cancelled" << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "pthread is terminated due to xxx?" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to the manpage of `pthread_join`:

> If the target thread was canceled, then PTHREAD_CANCELED is placed in *retval.

What are the possible return values of `pthread_join` when using `pthread_cancel`? Why `pthread_join` sometimes does not return `PTHREAD_CANCELED`?

Please note that I used the default cancel type (i.e. `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED`) and enable cancel (i.e. `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE`).

Comment: Is it possible that your thread just terminates on its own? In this case, `pthread_join()` returns the value returned by your thread functions.

Comment: @sstn: No because I added a print statement when it cancel the thread and another print statement in the else-statement of pthread_timedjoin_np. And the logs shows the thread is cancelled instead of terminating itself.